# Next Js - How to retrieve data from api requiring authorization (via axios)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, authorization, server-side-rendering

**[detailsdevis].js**

This is the file that causes me problems because when I deploy on vercel I am told token is undefined

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Layout,
  Form,
  Row,
  Col,
  Input,
  Divider,
  Upload,
  message,
  Modal,
  Select,
  Button,
} from "antd";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fr";
import Link from "next/link";
import { URL } from "../../urlapi";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  HeartFilled,
  EditFilled,
  CheckCircleOutlined,
  CloseCircleFilled,
} from "@ant-design/icons";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";
import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Content } = Layout;
const { Search } = Input;
const { TextArea } = Input;
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function Detailsdevis({ banniere, item }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  //const history = useHistory();

  const { Option } = Select;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [demandeid, setdemandeid] = useState(item);
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [addDevis, setAddDevis] = useState(false);

  const [demande, setdemande] = useState(null);
  const [loadingBan, setLoadingBan] = useState(false);

  const [bannieres, setBannieres] = useState(null);

  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

  const getBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
  };

  const handlePreview = async (file) => {
    file.preview = await getBase64(file.originFileObj);
  };
  const dum = ({ file, onSuccess }) => {
    onSuccess("ok");
  };

  const handleChange = ({ fileList }) => setFileList(fileList);

  const normFile = (e) => {
    console.log("Upload event:", e);
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };

  async function onSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);

    const Data = new FormData();
    Data.append("demandeid", demandeid);
    Data.append("description", values.description);
    Data.append("category", demande.category._id);
    Data.append("client", demande.owner._id);
    Data.append("doc", values.upload.file.originFileObj);
    const token =
      localStorage.getItem("user") &&
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.post(URL + "/api/devis/create", data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      setAddDevis(false);
      message.success("Envoi réussi!!");
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.response);
      setLoading(false);
      message.warning("Erreur enregistrement!");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const token =
      localStorage.getItem("user") &&
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;

    const getDemande = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(
          URL + "/api/demande/details/" + demandeid,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
          }
        );
        
        setLoading(false);

        setdemande(result.data);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.response && e.response.status == 401) {
          console.log("logout");
        }
      }
    };

    const getBan = async () => {
      setBannieres(banniere);
      setLoadingBan(false);
    };

    getBan();

    getDemande();
  }, [demandeid]);

  return (
    <Layout className=" bgwhite">
      <Header />

      <Content className="u-mar-top-xl ">
        <Layout className="bgapp  ">
          {bannieres != null && bannieres.length == 0 ? (
            <div
              style={{
                height: "250px",
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "#ddd",
              }}
            ></div>
          ) : (
            <img src={bannieres != null && bannieres[0].image} />
          )}

          <Row className="home-container  u-pad-vertical-m">
            {demande != null && (
              <>
                <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={24} className="flex">
                  <Col
                    xs={24}
                    sm={24}
                    md={18}
                    lg={18}
                    className="u-pad-horizontal-l u-pad-vertical-s  "
                  >
                    <div className="myspace-nav-menu">
                      <div className="no-padding">
                        <nav>
                          <ul>
                            <li className="active">
                              <Link href="/myspace/spacepro" title="">
                                <a>
                                  <i className="fa fa-chevron"></i> toutes les
                                  Demandes -
                                  {moment(demande.date_created).add(
                                    15,
                                    "days"
                                  ) < moment() ? (
                                    <>
                                      <CloseCircleFilled
                                        style={{ color: "red" }}
                                      />{" "}
                                      <span className="">Expiré</span>
                                    </>
                                  ) : (
                                    <>
                                      <CheckCircleOutlined
                                        style={{ color: "green" }}
                                      />{" "}
                                      <span className="">en cours</span>
                                    </>
                                  )}
                                </a>
                              </Link>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </nav>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="bgwhite u-pad-l">
                      <div className="lead">
                        <h4 className="flex justbtw">
                          <Link
                            href={"/detailsdevis/" + demande._id}
                            className="coltext av-heavy fs16"
                          >
                            <a>
                              {demande.typedemande} : {demande.category.name} |{" "}
                              {demande.subcategory.name}{" "}
                            </a>
                          </Link>
                          <a href="#">
                            {" "}
                            <HeartFilled />{" "}
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                        <h6>
                          {/* <span className="fs14"><span>ARIANA, </span> </span>  */}
                          <span className="fs14">
                            <span className="coltext av-heavy ">Posté le </span>
                            {moment(demande.date_created).format(
                              "DD-MMM-Y"
                            )}{" "}
                          </span>
                        </h6>

                        <h6>
                          {/* <span className="fs14"><span>ARIANA, </span> </span>  */}
                          <span className="fs14">
                            <span className="coltext av-heavy ">Adresse :</span>
                            {demande.adresse}{" "}
                          </span>
                        </h6>

                        <h6>
                          {/* <span className="fs14"><span>ARIANA, </span> </span>  */}
                          <span className="fs14">
                            <span className="coltext av-heavy ">
                              Prefère être appellé:
                            </span>{" "}
                            {demande.appel}{" "}
                          </span>
                          <span className="fs14" style={{ marginLeft: "2px" }}>
                            {" "}
                          </span>
                        </h6>
                        <br />
                        <p className="fs15">
                          Bonjour, <br /> {demande.description}{" "}
                        </p>
                        <Divider />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <Row className="u-pad-horizontal-s"></Row>
                  </Col>

                  <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={6} lg={6} className="u-mar-top-l">
                    <div className="widget bgwhite u-mar-bottom-l profile  u-pad-s flex column justcenter itemcenter">
                      <div className="profile-logo-container">
                        <div className="profile-logo">
                          <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="80" height="80">
                            <circle
                              fill="#F3F7FA"
                              cx="100"
                              cy="100"
                              r="100"
                            ></circle>
                            <path
                              fill="#BCC2D0"
                              d="M141.9 128.3c-27.1-1.4-79.3-.5-97.5-.1-7.9.2-15.6 2.6-22 7.2-4 2.9-7.9 6.9-10.2 12.3C29.1 178.9 62.1 200 100 200c13.3 0 26.4-2.6 38.6-7.7 8.3-3.7 16.1-8.5 23.3-14.1 2.5-12.9 7.1-48.5-20-49.9z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              fill="#E1E4EB"
                              d="M75.3 105.5l-.3 35.7c0 2.9.6 5.8 1.8 8.5l.2.5c3.6 8.2 12.1 13.1 21 12.1 4.2-.5 8.2-2.2 11.4-5 6.2-5.4 10.1-12.9 11.2-21l1.6-11.6-46.9-19.2z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              fill="#BCC2D0"
                              d="M118.5 144.5c.7-1.5 1.4-3.8 2.2-8.3l1.6-11.6-47-19.1 16.3 22.3c3.4 4.7 7.6 8.8 12.5 12 4.2 2.8 9.4 5.2 14.4 4.7z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              fill="#E1E4EB"
                              d="M148.5 82.1c-1.8 25-10.4 69.7-45 51.6 0 0-12.3-5.2-22.7-19.1-2.9-3.9-7.1-11.5-8.7-16.1L67.7 85c-6.1-16.6-3.3-35.4 8-49.1C82 28.2 95 22.2 108 22.3c22.8.2 31.2 10.4 36.1 24 3.2 8.8 5 26.5 4.4 35.8z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              fill="#BCC2D0"
                              d="M82 96.5c-1.5-5.3-10 2.1-10 2.1.9 2.4 2 4.7 3.2 7v3.1c5.2-1.6 8.3-7 6.8-12.2z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              fill="#97A0B6"
                              d="M83.3 11.4c-28.2 7.8-44.7 37.3-36.8 65.7 4.2 15.1 14.8 27.7 29.1 34.3v-10.7l4.5-9s38.5-14.6 53.2-49.3c0 0 5.4 15.1 11.8 27.6 1.2 2.5 2.5 4.9 3.7 7.1.1-.5.3-1 .4-1.5 2.1-8.9 2-18.1-.5-26.9-7.8-28.5-37.1-45.1-65.4-37.3z"
                            ></path>
                            <circle
                              fill="#E1E4EB"
                              cx="77.7"
                              cy="95.8"
                              r="9.9"
                            ></circle>
                          </svg>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="profile-info-container center u-mar-top-s">
                        {localStorage.getItem("user") &&
                        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).premium ? (
                          <>
                            <h4 className="coltext av-heavy fs16 u-mar-bottom-s">
                              {demande.owner.firstname} {demande.owner.lastname}
                            </h4>

                            <h4 className="coltext av-heavy fs16 u-mar-bottom-s">
                              Tel : {demande.owner.phone}
                            </h4>

                            <div className=" fs12 u-mar-bottom-xs">
                              Membre depuis{" "}
                              {moment(demande.owner.created_at).format(
                                "DD-MMM-Y"
                              )}
                            </div>
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          <>
                            <h4 className="coltext av-heavy fs16 u-mar-bottom-s">
                              ************
                            </h4>

                            <div className=" fs12 u-mar-bottom-xs">
                              Membre depuis{" "}
                              {moment(demande.owner.created_at).format(
                                "DD-MMM-Y"
                              )}
                            </div>
                          </>
                        )}

                        <span className="av-mediumfs16 ">
                          <span>
                            Contacté par ({demande.devis.length}) professionnels
                          </span>{" "}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    {localStorage.getItem("user") &&
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).premium &&
                    moment(demande.date_created).add(15, "days") > moment() ? (
                      <Button
                        type="primary"
                        htmlType="submit"
                        size="large"
                        onClick={() => setAddDevis(true)}
                        className="rad8 w100 u-mar-bottom-s"
                      >
                        <span className="fs18 av-heavy">
                          {" "}
                          Proposer un devis
                        </span>
                      </Button>
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        <Button
                          type="secondary"
                          htmlType="submit"
                          size="large"
                          onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(true)}
                          className="rad8 w100 u-mar-bottom-s"
                        >
                          <span className="fs18 av-heavy">
                            {" "}
                            Afficher le contact
                          </span>
                        </Button>

                        <Button
                          type="primary"
                          htmlType="submit"
                          size="large"
                          onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(true)}
                          className="rad8 w100 u-mar-bottom-s"
                        >
                          <span className="fs18 av-heavy">
                            {" "}
                            Proposer un devis
                          </span>
                        </Button>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                </Col>
              </>
            )}
          </Row>
        </Layout>
      </Content>

      <Modal
        title="Accès reservé aux abonnés"
        footer={null}
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onCancel={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}
      >
        <div className="flex column itemcenter jsutcenter">
          <h1 className="coltext fs28 av-heavy center">
            {" "}
            Accès reservé aux abonnés{" "}
          </h1>
          <h2 className="coltext fs20 av-medium center">
            {" "}
            Veuillez nous contacter pour acceder à toutes les fonctionnalités du
            site{" "}
          </h2>

          <span className="av-roman fs14 u-mar-top-l">
            {" "}
            Tel: 07 98 71 44 40 Lundi à vendredi : 8h30 à 17h{" "}
          </span>
          <span className="av-roman fs14 u-mar-top-s">
            {" "}
            Email : commercial@monsieurtravaux.ci
          </span>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Modal
        title="Envoyez un devis"
        footer={null}
        visible={addDevis}
        onCancel={() => setAddDevis(false)}
      >
        <div className="flex column itemcenter jsutcenter">
          <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onSubmit}>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={24}>
                <Form.Item name="description" label="Description">
                  <TextArea rows={3} style={{ height: "auto" }} />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>

              <Form.Item
                name="upload"
                label="Devis"
                rules={[
                  { required: true, message: "Veuillez choisir une devis" },
                ]}
              >
                <Upload
                  customRequest={dum}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  listType="picture"
                  onPreview={handlePreview}
                >
                  {fileList.length == 0 && (
                    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
                      Ajouter un fichier (pdf)
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </Upload>
              </Form.Item>
            </Row>

            <Form.Item className="w100">
              <Divider />
              <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => setAddDevis(false)}
                  size={"large"}
                  className="rad8 u-pad-horizontal-l"
                  style={{ marginRight: 12 }}
                >
                  Annuler
                </Button>
                <Button
                  size={"large"}
                  loading={loading}
                  type="primary"
                  htmlType="submit"
                  className="rad8 u-pad-horizontal-l"
                  type="primary"
                >
                  Envoyer
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const token = Cookies.get("user") && JSON.parse(Cookies.get("user")).token;
      const result = await axios.get(
        URL + "/api/demande/details/",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
        }
      );
  const datas = result.data;

  const paths = datas.map((secteur) => {
    return {
      params: { id: secteur._id.toString() },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const result = await axios.get(URL + "/api/banniere/Espace pro");

  return {
    props: {
      item: id,
      banniere: result.data,
    },
  };
}
```

here are the pieces of code that bother me a lot, and I would like to know why please?

```js
async function onSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);

    const Data = new FormData();
    Data.append("demandeid", demandeid);
    Data.append("description", values.description);
    Data.append("category", demande.category._id);
    Data.append("client", demande.owner._id);
    Data.append("doc", values.upload.file.originFileObj);
    const token =
      localStorage.getItem("user") &&
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.post(URL + "/api/devis/create", data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      setAddDevis(false);
      message.success("Envoi réussi!!");
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.response);
      setLoading(false);
      message.warning("Erreur enregistrement!");
    }
  }
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const token =
      localStorage.getItem("user") &&
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;

    const getDemande = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(
          URL + "/api/demande/details/" + demandeid,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
          }
        );
        
        setLoading(false);

        setdemande(result.data);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.response && e.response.status == 401) {
          console.log("logout");
        }
      }
    };

    const getBan = async () => {
      setBannieres(banniere);
      setLoadingBan(false);
    };

    getBan();

    getDemande();
  }, [demandeid]);
```

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const token = Cookies.get("user") && JSON.parse(Cookies.get("user")).token;
      const result = await axios.get(
        URL + "/api/demande/details/",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
        }
      );
  const datas = result.data;

  const paths = datas.map((secteur) => {
    return {
      params: { id: secteur._id.toString() },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const result = await axios.get(URL + "/api/banniere/Espace pro");

  return {
    props: {
      item: id,
      banniere: result.data,
    },
  };
}
```

***I want to be able to retrieve the details of each quote automatically knowing its id by retrieving the token that the server generates. this is my problem here actually***

Comment: You can't get cookies from inside `getStaticPaths`, that function runs on the server at build time and has no access to request-specific information like cookies. That can only be done on the client-side, or using `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: thanks you so much....